brainfuck program to print hello world forward and in reverse
I am looking to create a brainfuck program that can print the text "Hello, World" when executed--but not just that (it' s too easy), it should also proint "dlroW ,olleH" when the program is executed backwards. i.e
This code probably prints hello world.
>++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<.>++++[<+++++++>-]<+.+++++++..+++.>>++++++[<+++++++>-]<+
+.------------.>++++++[<+++++++++>-]<+.<.+++.------.--------.>>>++++[<++++++++>-
]<+.

but now i need a version such that when executed from the last character (. in this case) prints the same text in reverse.
Specifically, I need a hello world program such that when i run it through the rev command, it prints "dlroW ,olleH".
Shortest code wins! Better if you find a way to use loops.
Current implementation written in C.

Negative pointers not allowed.
Unlimited e†panding memory.
Understands only the eight brainfuck symbols and ignores everything else.

/*

    bf.c: A Brainf*** interpreter

    Copyright 2003 Erik Bosman <ejbosman@cs.vu.nl>

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MEMORY_UNIT char
// #define MEMORY_UNIT unsigned short int

#define INITIAL_MEMORY 1024 * sizeof(MEMORY_UNIT)
#define MEMORY_INCREASE 1024 * sizeof(MEMORY_UNIT)

typedef struct
{
    char type;
    long quantity;
    void *loop;
    void *next;
} Instruction;

FILE *programFile;
MEMORY_UNIT *memory, *limit, *p;
Instruction *program;

// Error messages

int die(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
    return 1;  // Avoid warnings
}

// Dynamic memory allocation

void initialize_memory(size_t size) {
    (memory = (MEMORY_UNIT *)malloc(size)) || die("Cannot allocate memory");
    limit = memory + size;
    memset(memory, 0, size);
}

void expand_memory(size_t size) {
    size_t memsize = limit - memory + size;
    size_t p_relative = p - memory;

    (memory = (MEMORY_UNIT *)realloc(memory, memsize)) || die("Cannot allocate memory");

    limit = memory + memsize;
    p = p_relative + memory;
    memset(limit - size, 0, size);
}

void free_list(Instruction *list) {
    Instruction *next;

    while (list->type != ']') {
        next = list->next;
        if (list->type == '[')
            free_list(list->loop);
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
    free(list);
}

// Loading

Instruction *load() {
    char c, c2 = 0;
    long l;

    Instruction *i = (Instruction *)malloc(sizeof(Instruction));
    Instruction *first = i;

    while (!feof(programFile)) {
        c = fgetc(programFile);
        i->type = c;
        l = 1;
        switch (c) {
            case '[':
                i->loop = load();
                break;
            case ']':
                return first;
            case '<':
            case '>':
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case ',':
            case '.':
                if (!feof(programFile)) {
                    while (!feof(programFile) && (c2 = fgetc(programFile)) == c) l++;
                    ungetc(c2, programFile);
                }
                i->quantity = l;
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
        i->next = (Instruction *)malloc(sizeof(Instruction));
        i = i->next;
    }
    i->type = ']';
    return first;
}

// Program execution

void execute(Instruction *i);

void run(Instruction *list) {
    while (list->type != ']') {
        execute(list);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

void execute(Instruction *i) {
    long l;

    switch (i->type) {
        case '>':
            p += i->quantity;
            while (p >= limit) expand_memory(MEMORY_INCREASE);
            return;
        case '<':
            if (p - i->quantity < memory)
                die("Negative memory pointer");
            p -= i->quantity;
            return;
        case '+':
            *p += i->quantity;
            return;
        case '-':
            *p -= i->quantity;
            return;
        case '.':
            for (l = 0; l < i->quantity; l++) putchar(*p);
            return;
        case ',':
            for (l = 0; l < i->quantity; l++) *p = getchar();
            return;
        case '[':
            while (*p) run(i->loop);
            return;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

// Main

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!(programFile = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    initialize_memory(INITIAL_MEMORY);

    p = memory + 0;

    program = load();

    run(program);

    free_list(program);

    free(memory);

    fclose(programFile);

    exit(0);
}


Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges! I added the [tag:source-layout] tag, which describes challenges similar to this. What's the scoring criterion for this challenge? I'd suggest [tag:code-golf], which makes the shortest solution the winner (all challenges need an objective winning criterion, so that if someone comes up with a valid answer, there's still a reason for people to try to compete)

I second that this would be interesting as code-golf. I can't think of any other reasonable scoring criterion. I strongly suggest you chose code-golf.

It might be a fun idea to have this same challenge that uses a BF variant where the first encountered bracket ([ or ]) defines the "opening" bracket, allowing loops to be used. (Since, I believe, in this challenge they simply cannot be used.)

@JonathanAllan Depends on what interpreter you choose. Since on this site, we define a language by its interpreter / compiler, there may have some interpreter that simply execute the code normally before hitting the unbalanced ]. However, it is not clear what brainfuck mean here in author's definition, since brainfuck actually have many dialect based on its type size, cell size, wrap behavior. And behavior ,more importantly, the behavior to unbalanced ], may vary between different implementations.

I think in light of the above the challenge is unclear. I think pointing to a specific BF implementation to resolve edge cases would make it perfectly clear. Otherwise I think this challenge could be reopened.

@tsh Current implement exits at the unbalanced ] and assumes infinite ]s at EOF, making solution likely do print("Hello World")]("Hello World")tnirp and it results in sum of two [tag:Kolmogorov-Complexity]

brainfuck, 1799 1584 bytes
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<.<..<<.<.<.<.>>>.>.>.<<<<<<.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Try it online! !enilno ti yrT Explanation: The characters dW ,orleH or Helro, Wd respectively are loaded into consecutive cells by the code at the start/reversed code at the end and then the code in the middle outputs the desired cells, repeating the l and o as they're the same distance away in either direction. Edit: Saved 213 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan.

For if/when this gets reopened: The l is repeated too, so 1590 / reversed. Might be able to shorten by reordering memory a little.

@JonathanAllan Aha, so the trick is that the duplicated letter is the same distance away whichever direction you look at it, and here was me thinking that the letter needed to be the same number of memory locations from each end...

Yes, four less is possible (at least): 1586 and reversed

@JonathanAllan Nice! I think I can get it down to 1584.

+1 for working code....BIG TICK for when you explain how it actually works..cant seem to fully grasp it

Formatted code a little for readability. (used this

brainfuck, 1998 bytes
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Try it online!
!enilno ti yrT
Maybe more golfable but for code to reverse, no loop is allowed

+1 for !enilno ti yrT

+1 for working code....BIG TICK for when you explain how it actually works..cant seem to fully grasp it
